# How to create a new MySQL database with ActiveRecord in a non-rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

I'm building a non-rails pure ruby app that uses ActiveRecord. I want to write a rake file that creates a database and tables for it. I try the following code

```
namespace :db do
  task :create do
    conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
    create_db = "CREATE DATABASE foo_dev"
    conn.execute(create_db)
  end
end
```

But this gives me

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
```

error. Well, this is obvious because I didn't connect ActiveRecord to any database.

What should I do?

---

EDIT: I want to create a MySQL database.

Comment: Does your app simply not use Rails, or not use Rails or a database all together?

Comment: it does not use Rails, but uses a MySQL db with ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for answers but as I've edited in my question, I forgot to mention that I want to create a MySQL DB. I've failed to create a MySQL db via ActiveRecord. Then I've solved the problem with the help of **mysql2** gem. Here's my solution:

```
client = Mysql2::Client.new(:host => 'localhost', :username=>"#{YOUR_MYSQL_USERNAME}", :password=> "#{YOUR_MYSQL_PASSWORD}")
client.query("CREATE DATABASE company_db")
client.query('USE company_db')
client.query('CREATE TABLE employees ...')
...
```

Here 'USE company_db' query is important because, it tells to the gem that we want to run queries on this database.

Comment: This seems problematic if you have to create all the tables explicitly instead of using ActiveRecord migrations / schema loading.

Answer (score 5):

Establish a Connection, some thing like:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
   :adapter   => 'sqlite3',
   :database  => './your_db.db'
)
```

For sqlite the database (file) gets created if it does not exist. Then perform a migration to create the tables.

Based on a previous question [Can ActiveRecord create tables outside of a migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358903/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect without the database, then create it, then connect with the database:

```rb
connection_options = { adapter: "mysql2", host: "127.0.0.1", username: "root" }
database = 'foo'
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(connection_options)
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_database(database)
rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
  # already exists ...
end
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(connection_options.merge(database: database))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `create_database` method off of the connection like so:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(connetion_params)
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_database('database_name')
```