# Sinatra Activerecord Error

Tags: sinatra

I have a problem with a small sinatra app I build my database

In Rakefile:

```
require 'sinatra/activerecord/rake'
require './todo'
```

In myApp.rb:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'shotgun'
require 'sinatra/activerecord'
set :database, "sqlite3:///foo.sqlite3"

class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

but when I run the app its return me this:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: todos: SELECT "todos".* FROM "todos"
```

Comment: With this information I can't help you sorry. When exactly do you get this exception? Is `./todo` your `myApp.rb`? And `"sqlite3:///foo.sqlite3"` should be `"sqlite3:foo.sqlite3"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that the table `todos` does not exist.

The solution is to create a table called `todos`. You can do that within the sqlite3 shell with `create table todos(params)` where params are whatever the different parameters the table is going to hold.

Doing this inside of the program, it's my understanding that ActiveRecord uses migrations to update databases. [@Morgan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97073/morgan) provided [a rakefile](http://github.com/morganp/Code-Dojo/blob/master/ORM/lesson-01/rakefile.rb) (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358903/can-activerecord-create-tables-outside-of-a-migration)) to do handle this.

Alternatively, you can look into [Datamapper](http://datamapper.org/) to handle your database interactions, which you might find easier to wrap your head around since you're not using rails.